# how do i get my stolen phone& pictures back?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

On 7 july 15 someone broke in my house and stole my galaxy note 3 it did not have service it has been disconnect for about 6mo now i would like to get my phone back because it had picture of me and my dad who died the day after father day this past june & other family pictures that can not be replaced.how do i go about getting those back?

Comment: Afraid there's not much we can do about here. Being disconnected for half a year, I see no way how you could locate it. Apart from which, the thief most likely already factory-reset the device to sell it. Sorry for these bad news.

Comment: @Izzy he could file a complain in the local police dept.

Comment: Sure he could. That doesn't make it much likely the police dept will restore the data the thief most likely already purged – provided they even find the device.

Answer (score 2):

I'm very sorry for what happened, but there isn't much that can be done.

You can only get your photos back if you had backed them up.

Try to remember if you had copied them to your PC, pendrive or CD.

Or if you had shared it with someone who might still have them.

If you had shared it in apps like *hangouts* then they will be backed up by *google+ photos*. And if you had set *photos* to back up all your images you can retrieve them easily by opening your account in another device. Every thing will be stored safe in google's servers.

Or probably you would have them on your *Google Drive*, *Dropbox* or any other cloud service.

And also, if you had your whole phone backed up by your google account (every time you log in to a google in your phone, google askes you if you want to back up your phone), then you can get back all your stuff like contacts and bookmarks back by logging in a different phone.

Hope this helps